# Calcular Valor Presente em Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-excel

Preciso calcular o valor presente equivalente a formula do Excel, tenho os seguintes dados:

VP(2,5%;48;-2052,50) que no excel me retorna o valor de 57.000,00 arredondando para baixo.

Alguém pode ajudar a fazer isto no javascript?

Tentei utilizar esta função que encontrei, mas não funcionou.

```
function PV(rate, nper, pmt)
{
    return pmt / rate * (1 - Math.pow(1 + rate, -nper));
}
```

Comment: Essa sua função está correta. Tente `PV(0.025, 48, -2052.5)`.

Comment: Realmente esta formulá funcionou para mim, o meu erro era colocar 2.5 no rate ao invés de 0.025. Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David,

O **VPL** (Valor Presente Líquido) é o valor de cada prestação/parcela (**PMT** = PayMenTs) "trazido" para a data zero à taxa de juros (**Rate**) para cada um dos N períodos (**Nper** = quantidade de períodos).

```
VPL = somatório (n = 1 até Nper) de PMT / (1 + Rate) ^ n
```

Somando cada parcela pela divisão desta parcela por um mais a taxa elevada ao número de cada período, você obtém o VPL.

Por exemplo: **PMT = 1.000**  , **Rate = 0,025** (2,5% ao período) e **Nper = 3**:

```
VPL = 1.000 / (1 + 0,025) ^ 1 + 1.000 / (1 + 0,025) ^ 2 + 1.000 / (1 + 0,025) ^ 3
```

Analise a fórmula que está usando que irá descobrir o motivo da diferença.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, agora entendi exatamente o que a formulá faz. E a função que eu postei funcionou para mim o único problema era estar passando o rate (taxa) como 2.5 e não 0.025. Obrigado!

Comment: Legal que você entendeu a fórmula "por dentro"..Bom trabalho!

Answer (score 1):

A função funciona, eu acredito que seja só adequá-la ao seu propósito:

```
function PV(rate, nper, pmt) {
    rate = parseFloat(rate) / 100.0;
    return pmt / rate * (1 - Math.pow(1 + rate, -nper));
}

var saida =  Math.round(PV(2.5,48,-2052.5));
console.log(saida.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Com a explicação do @Leo eu verifiquei que o erro era inserir 2.5 como taxa, para o meu calculo o correto seria 0.025, sendo assim a função está correta:

```
function PV(rate, nper, pmt)
{
    return pmt / rate * (1 - Math.pow(1 + rate, -nper));
}
```

A saída desta operação seria 57004.40

https://jsfiddle.net/a62a1ra0/